# How to efficiently check if an integer exist in a multiple range value in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, performance

The objective is to perform a particular procedure if the `counter` (i.e., idx) is within any of multiple range

In this case, the range is originated from a `df`, as below

```
df=pd.DataFrame(dict(rbot=[4,7,20],rtop=[8,10,25]))
```

For example, certain activity is fired if the `counter` integer value is within `(4-8)` OR `(20,25)`.

The following code should answer the following objective

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame(dict(rbot=[4,7,20],rtop=[8,10,25]))

r_bot=df['rbot'].values.tolist()
r_top=df['rtop'].values.tolist()
for idx in range (120):
    h=[True for x,y in zip(r_bot,r_top) if x <= idx <=y ]

    if True in h:
        print(f'Do some operation with  {idx}')
```

Which produce the following output

```
 Do some operation with  4
Do some operation with  5
Do some operation with  6
Do some operation with  7
Do some operation with  8
Do some operation with  9
Do some operation with  10
Do some operation with  20
Do some operation with  21
Do some operation with  22
Do some operation with  23
Do some operation with  24
Do some operation with  25
```

In actual implementation, the range pairs can be up to hundreds,whereas, the counter can be up to hundreds thousand. Hence, I am wondering whether this is more efficient of doing this?

Comment: `pd.cut` might be helpful

Comment: @rpb sorry, I had deleted my answer by accident.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one option is with pandas cut and an interval index:

```py
arr = np.arange(120)
intervals = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(df.rbot, df.rtop, closed='both')

for idx in arr:
    if intervals.contains(idx).any():
        print(f'Do some operation with  {idx}')


Do some operation with  4
Do some operation with  5
Do some operation with  6
Do some operation with  7
Do some operation with  8
Do some operation with  20
Do some operation with  21
Do some operation with  22
Do some operation with  23
Do some operation with  24
Do some operation with  25
```

With the updated example, the above code works :

```py
arr = np.arange(120)
intervals = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(df.rbot, df.rtop, closed='both')

for idx in arr:
    if intervals.contains(idx).any():
        print(f'Do some operation with  {idx}')

Do some operation with  4
Do some operation with  5
Do some operation with  6
Do some operation with  7
Do some operation with  8
Do some operation with  9
Do some operation with  10
Do some operation with  20
Do some operation with  21
Do some operation with  22
Do some operation with  23
Do some operation with  24
Do some operation with  25
```

Thanks to @user2246849 for the tests, which I think you should have a look and see if it meets your needs.

Comment: Thanks @sammy. For other use, apart from `for-loop`, the second alternative also work if you are using `while`. To extend sammy alternate suggestion,one can use `if idx in arr[pd.notna(out)].tolist()`

Comment: Hi @sammy. While this solution is the fastest, but it did suffer if there is an overlapping. For example `df=pd.DataFrame(dict(rbot=[4,7,20],rtop=[8,10,25]))`

Comment: Good catch @rpb, kindly extend your question with this, and include the expected output

Comment: Please check edited post

Comment: updated answer to match edited post

Answer (score 1):

You could try numpy broadcasting to create a boolean mask that returns True for the indices that fall between each pair of `rbot` and `rtop` values. Then multiply it with the `range` to get the relevant values. Finally, use `flatnonzero` to select the True values:

```py
import numpy as np
arr = np.arange(120)
msk = ((df[['rbot']].to_numpy() <= arr) & (arr <= df[['rtop']].to_numpy())).sum(axis=0)
out = np.flatnonzero(msk*arr)
for idx in out:
    print(f'Do some operation with  {idx}')
```

Output:

```
Do some operation with  4
Do some operation with  5
Do some operation with  6
Do some operation with  7
Do some operation with  8
Do some operation with  20
Do some operation with  21
Do some operation with  22
Do some operation with  23
Do some operation with  24
Do some operation with  25
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of ways to approach this, here's one~

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(rbot=[4,20],rtop=[8,25]))
df.rtop += 1
for idx in range(120):
    if any(idx in range(*df.iloc[x]) for x in df.index):
        print(f'Do some operation with  {idx}')
```

Output:

```
Do some operation with  4
Do some operation with  5
Do some operation with  6
Do some operation with  7
Do some operation with  8
Do some operation with  20
Do some operation with  21
Do some operation with  22
Do some operation with  23
Do some operation with  24
Do some operation with  25
```

Answer (score 1):

FYI, if you exclusively want to perform an operation for each valid index and not intend to perform any additional aggregations later that would require pandas, this is way faster and memory efficient:

```
import pandas as pd

rbot = [i*1000 for i in range(10000)]
rtop = [(i+1)*1000-2 for i in range(10000)]
main_range = (0, 120)

df=pd.DataFrame(dict(rbot=[4,20],rtop=[8,25]))

intervals = zip(df['rbot'], df['rtop'])
for i in intervals:
    overlap = range(max(main_range[0], i[0]), min(main_range[1], i[-1])+1)
    for idx in overlap:
         print(f'Do some operation with  {idx}')
```

Just compute the overlap of the main range with the subranges.

```
Do some operation with  4
Do some operation with  5
Do some operation with  6
Do some operation with  7
Do some operation with  8
Do some operation with  20
Do some operation with  21
Do some operation with  22
Do some operation with  23
Do some operation with  24
Do some operation with  25
```

### Runtimes with larger dataset:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

rbot = [i*1000 for i in range(10000)]
rtop = [(i+1)*1000-2 for i in range(10000)]
main_range = (0, 120000)

df = pd.DataFrame({'rbot': rbot, 'rtop': rtop})

def python():
    intervals = zip(df['rbot'], df['rtop'])
    for i in intervals:
        overlap = range(max(main_range[0], i[0]), min(main_range[1], i[-1])+1)
        for idx in overlap:
            pass#print(idx)

# 5.03 ms ± 58 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
%timeit python()

def pandas():
    arr = np.arange(*main_range)
    
    intervals = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(df.rbot, df.rtop, closed='both')

    out = pd.cut(arr, intervals)

    out = arr[pd.notna(out)]
    
    for idx in out:
        pass#print(idx)

# 67 ms ± 467 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
%timeit pandas()


def numpy():
    arr = np.arange(*main_range)
    msk = ((df[['rbot']].to_numpy() <= arr) & (arr <= df[['rtop']].to_numpy())).sum(axis=0)
    out = np.flatnonzero(msk*arr)
    for idx in out:
        pass#print(idx)

# 2.77 s ± 7.48 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)    
%timeit numpy()
```

Comment: @sammywemmy ah yes, absolutely. I wasn't implying your answer isn't valid. I edited the post to make this aspect clearer! I also included the numpy approach, which requires a lot of memory so I had to shrink the range.

Comment: no worries ... I deleted my comment so I don't send the wrong message. Appreciate the tests